# Word for working with disruptions, with more mistakes than acceptable

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for doing work like this? For example when you have a lot of outages, you would say your power supplier is working *...ly.* Something like *inconsistent* or *erratic* but with a less forgiving connotation.

Comment: My power supply would be working ***intermittently***

Comment: Oh not supply, supplier... The power company...  ***undependably, unreliably***.

Answer (score 3):

A word often used in this connection is *sporadic*.

sporadic (adj.): occurring occasionally, singly, or in irregular or random instances

[MW online entry for 'sporadic'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sporadic)

Answer (score 0):

Your power supplier is working ineffectively.

ineffective

1:  not producing an intended effect

2:  not capable of performing efficiently or as expected

source: Merriam-Webster

Comment: Another possibility is _sporadically_.

Comment: @Blaise Zydeco Sporadically is a good word.  Write it up with definition, source and link as an answer, ping me and I will upvote.  (Need def, source and link!)

Comment: @ab2 Now posted as answer. Hope it's enough...